# Changing terminal Java version - not all options shown

Tags: linux, terminal, java, jdk

I'm trying to change the JDK that the linux terminal is using to run jar files from 1.6 to 1.7. I'm trying to do this by using the command `update-alternatives --config java` which is giving me the following output:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.7                                 1047      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
```

However if I go to the directory `/usr/lib/jvm` I can see that `java-7-openjdk-amd64` is present (among others).

What is the problem that is not causing this option to show when issuing the command `update-alternatives --config java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to add it to the list of options by running `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add it as an option first?

This is from the man page.

update-alternatives --install link name path priority [--slave link name path]...

Add a group of alternatives to the system.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do

Comment: I used the following command and got the following result `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-jdk jdk-7 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/jre/bin/java 1062
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_75/ to provide /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-jdk (jdk-7) in auto mode
` but the option still doesn't show.